# Почему uuid.uuid1() на Ubuntu всё время разный?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, uuid

В программе на Python использую `uuid.uuid1().node` для привязки софта к компьютеру. На компьютере c Windows 10 проблем нет, т.к. всегда выдаётся значение MAC-адреса, но в случае с Ubuntu 20.04 `uuid.uuid1().node` после каждой перезагрузки генерит новый код.

Почему такое разное поведение, и как у Ubuntu получить MAC?

Comment: Странно, в моей Ubuntu 20.04 `node` всегда одинаковый. Может, у вас как-то по особенному настроена сеть?

Comment: Доступна ли команда `ip`? Если нет, попробуйте установить `sudo apt-get install iproute2`

Comment: По `ip a` в link/ether всегда выдаётся один и тот же MAC. А вот `uuid.uuid1().node` каждый раз новый после перезагрузки.

Comment: Наверное потому что `Функция uuid1() модуля uuid создает UUID из идентификатора хоста node и порядкового номера **текущего времени** clock_seq.`: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-uuid-python/funktsib-uuid1-modulja-uuid/

Comment: @andreymal, эээээ стоп. `Текущее время` - каждый раз меняется, потому что это ВРЕМЯ. Как `постоянная+переменная` будет давать одинаковый результат?

Comment: А, я тупой, пропустил кусок с `.node`. Сорян.